# Key error in JSON when using loop

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have been trying to pull out elements from a large JSON dictionary but when using a loop in Python 3 it has a 'key error' after a few iterations.

The 'label' works fine but when trying to extract the 'value' it gives the key error.  Any thoughts on what i'm doing wrong?

Example of the JSON i am using:

```
{ 
"@context" : "nullflood-monitoring/meta/context.jsonld" ,
"meta" : { 
"publisher" : "Environment Agency" ,
"licence" : "http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/doc/open-government-
licence/version/3/" ,
"documentation" : "nullflood-monitoring/doc/reference" ,
"version" : "0.9" ,
"comment" : "Status: Beta service" ,
"hasFormat" : [ "nullflood-monitoring/id/measures.csv", "nullflood-
monitoring/id/measures.rdf", "nullflood-monitoring/id/measures.ttl", 
"nullflood-monitoring/id/measures.html" ]
}
,
"items" : [ { 
"@id" : "nullflood-monitoring/id/measuresures/1029TH-level-downstage-i-
15_min-mASD" ,
"datumType" : "nullflood-monitoring/def/core/datumASD" ,
"label" : "RIVER DIKLER AT Bournemouth ON ON THE WATER - level-downstage-i-
15_min-mASD" ,
"latestReading" : { 
  "@id" : "nullflood-monitoring/data/readings/1029TH-level-downstage-i-
15_min-mASD/2018-02-10T12-00-00Z" ,
  "date" : "2018-02-10" ,
  "dateTime" : "2018-02-10T12:00:00Z" ,
  "measure" : "nullflood-monitoring/id/measures/1029TH-level-downstage-i-
15_min-mASD" ,
  "value" : -0.283
}
 ,
"notation" : "1029TH-level-downstage-i-15_min-mASD" ,
"parameter" : "level" ,
"parameterName" : "Water Level" ,
"period" : 900 ,
"qualifier" : "Downstream Stage" ,
"station" : "nullflood-monitoring/id/stations/1029TH" ,
"stationReference" : "1029TH" ,
"unit" : "http://qudt.org/1.1/vocab/unit#Meter" ,
"unitName" : "mASD" ,
"valueType" : "instantaneous"
 }
 , { 
"@id" : "nullflood-monitoring/id/measures/1029TH-level-stage-i-15_min-mASD" 
,
"datumType" : "nullflood-monitoring/def/core/datumASD" ,
"label" : "RIVER DIKLER AT BOURTON ON THE WATER - level-stage-i-15_min-mASD" 
,
"latestReading" : { 
  "@id" : "nullflood-monitoring/data/readings/1029TH-level-stage-i-15_min-
mASD/2018-02-10T12-00-00Z" ,
  "date" : "2018-02-10" ,
  "dateTime" : "2018-02-10T12:00:00Z" ,
  "measure" : "nullflood-monitoring/id/measures/1029TH-level-stage-i-15_min-
mASD" ,
  "value" : 0.245
}
```

The Python code i have so far:

```
data = json.loads(source)

for each in data['items']:
    label = (each['label'])
    value = (each['latestReading']['value'])
print(label, value)
```

My first post on here so apologies if its not formatted correctly.

Comment: What is the exact error message? Are you sure all the items have a `"latestReading"` object with a `"value"`?

Comment: It gives: KeyError: 'latestReading' after printing the first six or so 'values'

Comment: Your JSON dosen't seem correct, did you check it before trying to loop thru?
You can check it here: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: Or even label? Without seeing the whole json it is hard to know

Comment: The JSON is huge, over 82,000 rows.  Is there anywhere web app i can use to check it. @Enzo suggestion won't load the JSON in without error.  I am pulling the JSON from here: https://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/measures.

Comment: @hamsy did you try to paste the JSON here: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is broken, I took the JSON directly from the link you gave at 
[one of your comments](https://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/measures)
Running it with your code resulted exactly in the exception you mentioned, I then added an exception handling code that simply continues iterating over the JSON:

```
data = json.loads(source)

for each in data['items']:
    try:
        label = (each['label'])
        value = (each['latestReading']['value'])
        print(label, value)
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

Here is the output of the program *(It was too large, so I posted it on pastebin)*:

https://pastebin.com/tGfSnZv0

I'm not sure if the output is ideal, but I'm hoping that it will go some way to help you solve your issue, it certainly seems far more descriptive than only 6 results.
My guess is that the JSON that the UK government updates is inconsistent or there's some syntax involved I'm not aware of.

Comment: Thanks very much! Does this simply skip where it cannot find the key 'latestReading'?

Comment: Yes, you could also try to see if the `latestReading` key does not exist without using exceptions, but the result is the same.